# List as a look up value from another site

Tags: list, lookup-column

I would like to use a list from one site as a look up for another site. Can I do this with out using code.  Only use OOTB or Designer? Or is there a better way?

Comment: There are 3rd party products,http://www.sharepointadd-ons.com/sharepoint-cross-site-lookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under similar constraints in MOSS, my method has been to create a list at some "top level" site. Then, at that site, create a Site Column that is a lookup to the list. Site Columns are inherited downward so, in any site below that site, you can select "add from existing site columns" and now you've got a cross-site lookup without even needing designer.

In 2010, we're mostly replacing this approach with managed metadata.

Comment: Yes. Managed Metadata seems like the way to go.  Thanks